# VBScript- Input DisplayName Output AD Username

Tags: active-directory, vbscript, powershell-v3.0

If I had a txt file with a bunch of names:

Dan Smith
Jim Bob
Ryan Jones
etc,etc

using a VBscript could I convert the displaynames to AD Usernames?

If Powershell is only options, could you please let me know how I could format my text file for it to run. I would rather use VBscript, but Powershell will work.

Answer (score 1):

If your text file is 1 name per line and you know they show up exactly like they do in AD.

```
Get-Content Names.txt | Get-Aduser -filter {Name -eq '$_'} | select Name,Samaccountname
```

At least thats a way to do it in PowerShell.